# Why Kolmogorov distribution function is a distribution function

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

How to prove that distribution function of Kolmogorov distribution is a distribution function? In particular, that it is 1 in infinity and is increasing function.

$$ F(x) =
\begin{cases}
\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} (-1)^k e^{-2k^2 x^2}, & x > 0; \\
0, & x \leqslant 0.
\end{cases} $$

Comment: it can't be increasing, look at $(-1)^k$ terms

Comment: It is increasing, otherwise it won't be a distribution function. $(-1)^k$ term is inside the sum and does not depend on x.

Comment: Maybe the form of the Kolmogorov distribution function on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Kolmogorov_distribution) will be more helpful. Where in the proof are you stuck?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function is relevant.